# Shifting letters in a word alphabetically

Tags: c, character, ascii

I'm currently working a project involving shifting letters in a word and further working with all possible outcomes.

It should work like this:
e.g:

> helloworld
> ifmmpxpsme
> jgnnqyqtnf

...and so on.
Since I'm new to programming and quite stuck on this matter, could anyone please give me a hint on how to successfully manage just that ? I know it can't be that difficult and it maybe has something to do with ASCII letter representation, however, I don't know, how to perform this. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: In ASCII (which your computer likely uses) `'a' + 1` gives `'b'`, ..., `'y' + 1` gives `'z'`... `'z' + 1` gives something else, and similarly for uppercase letters.

Comment: spanorange, Please explain how "helloworld ifmmpxpsme jgnnqyqtnf" is an example of your goal.  Perhaps a more simple example, with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try reading this [site](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), it shows the ASCII table very clearly.

In ASCII very character was its own unique value for example `'T'` is equal to `84` and `'t'` is equal to `116`. So, if we add `+1` to them it will become `'S'` and `'s'` respectively and same logic goes for `-1`.

##### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static char *shift(const char *word)
{
    if (!word)
        return NULL;
    char *ptr = calloc(strlen(word) + 1, sizeof(char));
    if(!ptr)
        return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; word[i]; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(word[i]))
            return NULL;
        ptr[i] = word[i] + 1;
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *word = shift("helloworld");
    while (word)
    {
        puts(word);
        word = shift(word);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

##### Output:

```
ifmmpxpsme
jgnnqyqtnf
khoorzruog
lipps{svph
```

Comment: Detail: note that `isalpha(word[i])` is UB when `word[i] < 0`. `*word` may be outside the ASCII range.